# Debian 10 buster apt update failed - Read-only file system

Tags: debian, readonly

Auto updates are enabled on my Debian 10 buster server.
I noticed however that many errors appeared when I ran **apt update** command manually:

```
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_buster_updates_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP:]
Hit:3 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Err:3 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.eYF3oi for passing config to apt-key
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease
Err:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.CraMte for passing config to apt-key
Hit:5 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease
Err:5 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.PnxFvd for passing config to apt-key
Hit:6 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
Err:6 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.YH5tQi for passing config to apt-key
Hit:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
Err:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.nny8ap for passing config to apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.AK6iXs - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.IWp7Gu - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.aIUVqw - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.qFwKay - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.a5kzUz - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.EGgoEB - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_buster_updates_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_buster_updates_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.eYF3oi for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f12.x_dists_buster_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f12.x_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f12.x_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f12.x_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.nodesource.com_node%5f12.x_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.CraMte for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_7.x_apt_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_7.x_apt_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_7.x_apt_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_7.x_apt_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_7.x_apt_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.PnxFvd for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.sury.org_php_dists_buster_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.sury.org_php_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.sury.org_php_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.sury.org_php_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.sury.org_php_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.YH5tQi for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_buster_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_buster_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_debian_dists_buster_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.nny8ap for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
```

I think the error was caused by the fact that the server was not shutdown correctly.

Could you please help me to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Make a filesystemcheck from a live linux and test your harddrive with smartmontools.

Comment: Thx for the answer. The server runs actually on a virtual machine. Only our infra team has direct access on it.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the error was caused by the fact that the server was not
> shutdown correctly.

That was actually the main problem from what [I read here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1137752)

My others Ubuntu instances were affected by the same problem. I restarted the servers in order to fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible remount the filesystem as read/write, but DON'T do that. I would suggest running fsck on the filesystem, which will require a reboot since it will have to have write access to fix any errors.

How to force fsck at reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -rF now
```

or  (if you can write to /)

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo reboot now
```